# Angular cannot receive response from WCF

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf, rest, post

I hava a WCF server written in C# and .NET 4.0

I'm trying to send a post request but I didn't receive answer from the browser.

This is my angular service.

```
services.factory('CodiciComunicazioneCreaFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://myIpAddress:port/service/create', { port : ':8002' },  {
            create: { method: 'POST', 
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } } 
        });
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried also to call my ws from curl with this command and all works perfectly.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Code":"aaa"}' http://myIpAddress:8002/servive/create
```

** EDIT **

Curl Output setting in XML response in the WCF.

```
~$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Code":"aaa"}' http://192.168.1.147:8002/CodiciComunicazione/create

<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

Setting in the WCF server the response as Json, with the same command, curl return simply

```
true
```

Comment: What happens when you make the request? 500 Error? Some other error? No response at all?

Comment: Is the machine running `curl` and the one running the AngularJS app the same machine? Is this all just running on localhost?

Comment: Yes, the machine running curl is the one that run angular. The WCF in in another host. 
I set a breakpoint on my WCF and when I make a request with angular it seems it's not triggered

Comment: 205ms is a pretty short timeout, what error is happening? You should see something in the browser debug console

Comment: The short time is probably because the WCF server in on a Virtual Machine. Unfortunatly I don't have any other error also in debug browser.

Comment: Show the full output of your `curl` command, with the exact IP address, port, and URL